# Using Python Map and Reduce Functions Together Correctly

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tuple (`seedTuple` in the code below) that itself contains 8 tuples, inside of each of which is a pair of 0D numpy arrays.  A function, conflateDistributions, combines each tuple of arrays sequentially to yield a single pair of 0D numpy arrays as a result.  The code below accomplishes the desired operations and gives the output in the desired format:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
numBins=100
rng=np.random.default_rng(1)    #Random number generator object
probArray=rng.random((8,numBins))   #Random numbers over 8x100 array
probArray=probArray/np.sum(probArray,axis=1,keepdims=True)    #Normalize each row so that probability sums to 1
valueArray=rng.integers(0,numBins,(8,numBins))  #Make array of values corresponding to probability array
seedTuple=tuple(zip(probArray,valueArray))  
def conflateDistributions(tuple1,tuple2):
    #Each tuple should be of length 2, with the first entry being a histogram count frequency and the second being bin centers
    conflateProbability=np.multiply.outer(tuple1[0],tuple2[0])
    #conflateBinCenters takes the bin centers provided and adds every combination of them
    conflateBinCenters=np.add.outer(tuple1[1],tuple2[1])
    leftBinEdge1=np.amin(tuple1[1])
    leftBinEdge2=np.amin(tuple2[1])
    rightBinEdge1=np.amax(tuple1[1])
    rightBinEdge2=np.amax(tuple2[1])
    newProbs,binsConflated=np.histogram(conflateBinCenters,bins=numBins,\
            range=(leftBinEdge1+leftBinEdge2-((rightBinEdge1-leftBinEdge1+rightBinEdge2-leftBinEdge2)/(2*(numBins-2))),\
                    rightBinEdge1+rightBinEdge2+((rightBinEdge1-leftBinEdge1+rightBinEdge2-leftBinEdge2)/(2*(numBins-2)))),\
                        weights=conflateProbability)
    centersConflated=0.5*(binsConflated[:-1]+binsConflated[1:])
    return (newProbs,centersConflated)
combinedWeights,combinedBins=reduce(conflateDistributions,seedTuple)
```

Now the twist:  instead of just 1 `seedTuple`, I actually have a list of ~2000 `seedTuple`s on which I need to execute the same operation (reduce(conflateDistribution)) as above.  I will be repeating this sequence of operations numerous times, so I am looking for an efficient non-for-loop approach to run the reduce(conflateDistributions) operations on all 2000 elements.  I wanted to use something along the lines of:

```
actualDataSizeList=[seedTuple for ii in np.arange(2000)]  #Example only, data in each seedTuple is not typically identical
overallCombinedWeights,overallCombinedBins=map(reduce(conflateDistributions),actualDataSizeList)
```

But I receive the error "TypeError: reduce expected at least 2 arguments, got 1".  I understand why reduce is throwing that error, but I would love some help with how to correct this syntax such that the output is a size 2000 list or array with each element containing 2 arrays (`combinedWeights` & `combinedBins`).

Python version 3.9.7

Comment: `map` and `reduce` are not more efficient than a regular for-loop. This is crucial to understand

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I got to the sort of one-line solution for which I was searching, described below.  You are correct that this approach (with map(reduce)) is roughly the same run time as a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`functools.partial()` is probably what you want.

```
iterator = map(functools.partial(reduce, conflateDistributions), actualDataSizeList)
for combinedWeights, combinedBins in iterator:
    # do stuff with each result
```

Note that this probably won't be much faster than just doing it inside the for loop (python still runs it in serial), but it will use less memory than making a list immediately. If you want to do it in parallel, take a look at `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Comment: this is a beautiful line of code.  Thank you for taking the time to understand my question and provide such a succinct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner combines the tuples stored in one element of actualDataSizeList using conflateDistributions, while map repeats that operation for each element of actualDataSizeList:

```
combinedHistograms=list(map(lambda row: reduce(conflateDistributions,row),actualDataSizeList))
```

The output `combinedHistograms` is a list of the same length as actualDataSizeList, with each element containing two arrays (`combinedWeights` & `combinedBins`).

Comment: How is this different than the other solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, It is not different, that was an oversight on my part, thank you for flagging it.  Upvoting yut23, thank you for the neat solution.